# Make brackets appear when I refer to an equation (with the help of \def or \newcommand)

Tags: macros

I want to define a newcommand that allows me to write just `\ref{Label}` instead of `(\ref{\label})`. I tried

```
\newcommand{\reff[1]}{(\ref{[#1]})}
```

and

```
\def\ref[#1]{(\ref{#1})}
```

but both of them did not work correctly.
My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\reff[1]}{(\ref{[#1]})}
\def\ref[#1]{(\ref{#1})}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{EQ}
a=b
\end{equation}
The eq \reffEQ or \refEQ ... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your second attempt won't work, you would need to use`\let\oldref\ref` (off the top of my head) before it at the very  least.  In your first attempt you've got a stray set of square brackets in the function defintion, and have you remembered to call `\reff` instead of `\ref`? *In general we need a **minimum working example** to help -- that means the smallest .tex file that will compile and demonstrate the problem*.  You may find the cleverref package helps you here rather than writing your own -- that's abit of a guess though.

Comment: `\eqref` (defined in `amsmath`) should do the trick.

Comment: It will never work, `\refEQ` is a macro call, not a macro given an argument. You should go with Bernards suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for your comments.  @Bernard, yes that works. Do anyone have a suggestion by using `\def` of `\newcommand` to abbreviate it.

Comment: Abbreviate `\eqref`? It's not that long, and syntax completion in your editor will be much more efficient. Maybe using `\cref/\Cref` from `cleveref` might be useful, as  typing, say, `\we see from \cref{eq:1}` will produce `we see from equation (1)`, saving you typing the name of the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest abbreviation would be a command symbol, but that's not advisable, so let's use a short name: `\qr` (e**q**uation **r**eference)

I used `\NewDocumentCommand` to provide for a starred variant that falls back to the usual `\eqref` definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand{\qr}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \eqref{#2}%
  }{%
    \fbox{\ref{#2}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a=b \label{EQ}
\end{equation}

In equation  \qr{EQ} we see some simple relation,

but \qr*{EQ} does look better
\end{document}
```